# ASP.NET MVC3 (C#) Image from URL to database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

This seems like a really easy problem however after extensive searching I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. What is the best possible implementation for pulling an image from a url and saving it to a SQL database?

I'm using MVC3 in C# and Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download that image from URL then save it in database

```
     string tnail = "";
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
    using (Image src = Image.FromFile("http://www.example.com/image.jpg"))
                        {
                            using (Bitmap dst = new Bitmap(25, 33))
                            {
                                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dst))
                                {
                                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
                                    g.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, dst.Width, dst.Height);
                                }
                                tnail = tname;
                                tnail = Path.ChangeExtension(tnail, null);
                                tnail += "_thumbnail";
                                tnail = Path.ChangeExtension(tnail, "jpg");
                                dst.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(imagepath), tnail), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: `Image.FromFile()` does not accept uri as an argument as it would throw `ArgumentException`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way is not to save it directly in the database, but to store a reference to a central file storage.

That said, you might have a look at [Inserting image over 3mb via linq-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824042/inserting-image-over-3mb-via-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you have a persistable entity (named `ImageFile` below) that has a byte array property representing the file, you can use `[WebClient.DownloadData][1]`.

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var img = new ImageFile();
    img.Data = client.DownloadData("http://www.example.com/image.jpg");

    // continue with saving your file.    
}
```